# How to get rid of "Partial upgrade" after crash while installing updates

Tags: apt, dpkg, update-manager, partial-upgrade

The other day I was installing updates while suddenly my laptop crashed (battery unplugged..) 
Now I receive the following dialog whilst opening the update manager:

[image: partial upgrade]

So far I've tried the following commands without succes
(in this order):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a 

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I also noticed in 'sourcecode' was selected in software sources. I unselected and reloaded repositories but no chance whatsoever.

I saw the following line in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Could it be this has something to do with it?
What else could I do to cancel it because doing this partial upgrade could cause a lot of problems as I understand (see this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/U%2B1/partial_upgrade))

Comment: What that error says I have no idea!

Comment: you want to upgrade or cancel it?

Comment: @george -- looks like a notice to finish the upgrade

Comment: @george I've changed thd screenshot to English

Comment: @wouter205 did you click the partial upgrade button?

Comment: @george: no I don't dare to do as I've read it can break dependencies (see also the link in my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem. I'm not 100% sure what the final solution was but it went as following:

1. Disabled out of date/unreachable PPA's

   I got an error notification regarding wine which was missing some dependencies (fyi: http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu & http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian)
2. Clean up aptitude cache:

   sudo apt-get clean 
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get upgrade

After this, update manager is functioning again.

Edit 24/09/17:

The previous answer was incorrect. I did the 'partial upgrade' which updated all the packages which were interupted in the previous update.

So to summarize: you can do the 'partial upgrade' without harm. The warning on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/U%2B1/partial_upgrade) is not applicable to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Restart your PC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it won't work you can contact me on discord.
Pro#0116